# Get the first 3 records from database with django

Tags: python, django, web

I have a problem. I want to get with a django query the first 3 records from my database and I really don't have any idea how can I do that. I didn't find nothing for this.

Comment: Please add some code. You ever worked with djang? ORM? an simple solution would be `[:3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
Model.objects.all().order_by('id')[:3]
```

This will order you model from first to last, and you take the first 3 elements, django will optimize the request adding a limit(3)